# Blahut Arimoto Algorithm for Rate Distortion for Sources with Memory

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, algorithms, information-theory

I would like to know if the [Blahut-Arimoto algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blahut%E2%80%93Arimoto_algorithm), for computing the channel capacity and rate distortion function, is solely limited to sources that are memoryless. Is there a version of this algorithm (a generalization of it) that handles sources with memory?

Comment: You might be interested in [A Generalization of the Blahut–Arimoto Algorithm to Finite-State Channels](http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~alek/Archive/2008/J33.pdf) (Vontobel et al, 2008) which considers channels whose memory consists in a finite-state machine.

Comment: I have a continuous Gaussian source with a given correlation function. I would like to know for example the 10th order R(D) function for this source.